# UITableView partially hidden by UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a `UITabBarController` which contains a `UINavigationController`. Within the visible `UIViewController`, I'm creating a `UITableView` programatically as follows:

```
self.voucherTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.voucherTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

However, the UITabBar is overlapping the `UITableView`.

When I output the height of the `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`, it returns 460.00 whereas it should be 367.00.

In Interface Builder, I'm using the 'Simulated Metrics' which automatically sets the height of the view to 367.00.

Is there something I'm missing, no matter what I try I can't see to get the 367.00 height that I need.

As a temp fix, I've set the frame of the `UITableView` manually, this isn't really ideal so it would be nice to work out why this isn't working:

```
self.voucherTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: Maybe you should check the autoSizingMasks of the tableView

Comment: I've updated my original post with what I'm setting the `autoresizingMask` value to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use self.view.bounds rather than [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] as the last one returns you the whole screen frame while self.view.bounds provides you with your view bounds wich seems what you are searching for.

Comment: I tried outputting the value of self.view.bounds.size.height and it returned 460.00 again.

Comment: Where are you trying to do so. It will be updated in -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated; (maybe in -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; also, but I'm unsure about it)

Comment: Another stuff that you should be aware of is the wantsFullScreenLayout property. If you set it to YES for your UIViewController it will update your view accordinly without taking tab bar into account.

Comment: ah I see, if I output the bounds in the viewDidAppear method, it returns me the correct result. At the moment I'm setting up my UITableView in the viewDidLoad, I'll try it in the viewDidAppear.

Comment: That worked, if I setup the UITableView in the viewDidAppear method and use the self.view.bounds, it appears correctly. Thanks.

Comment: It's better to set it up in viewDidAppear and only apply frame change in viewDidAppear, but in that case you'll need to hold a pointer to your tableView.

Comment: I assume you mean setup in the viewDidLoad and then made the frame change in the viewDidAppear? I already hold a pointer to the UITableView so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `UINavigationController` instance to the `UITabBarController` and then add a table view controller to the `rootViewController` property of the `UINavigationController` instance which should make your life a lot easier.

As a simple example of this, create an empty window-based application (the templates make this a lot more confusing than it really is).

Add your `UIViewController/UITableViewController` subclasses to the project then use this code as a guide to setting up your project. This code is in your AppDelegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // create our table view controller that will display our store list    
    StoresViewController *storeListController = [[StoresViewController alloc] init];


    // create the navigation controller that will hold our store list and detail view controllers and set the store list as the root view controller
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:storeListController];
    [navController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"TableView"];
    [navController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cart.png"]];


    // create our browser view controller    
    BrowserViewController *webBrowserController = [[BrowserViewController alloc] init];
    [webBrowserController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"WebView"];
    [webBrowserController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"web.png"]];

    // add our view controllers to an array, which will retain them
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, webBrowserController, nil];


    // release these since they are now retained
    [navController release];
    [storeListController release];
    [webBrowserController release];


    // add our array of controllers to the tab bar controller
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];


    // set the tab bar controller as our root view controller    
    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];


    // we can release this now since the window is retaining it
    [tabBarController release];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In the code sample above the `BrowserViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` and the `StoresViewController` class is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. The `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` instances are created programmatically and added to the window.

By subclassing the `UITableViewController` class you avoid having to create a `UITableView` instance programmatically and get most everything you need out of the box.

When you need to push a detail view onto the `UINavigationController` instance's stack, you just have use something similar to this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YourDetailViewControllerInstance animated:YES];
```

This will add the detail view `UIViewController` subclass to the `UINavigationController` instance's view hierarchy for you and animate the transition.

Lots of controllers in this, but it's totally worth it and will avoid a lot of the problems you're experiencing as this method allows the views to manage resizing and take toolbars/navigation bars into account all by themselves.