# iOS - UITableViewCell is covered by the UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitableview

As per the screen shot below, half of the last UITableViewCell is covered by the UITabBar:

[image]

I want to change to display full content of the last UITableViewCell as below, how can I do that?

[image]

Thanks

UPDATED

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [shopSection count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [cc getShopSectionRow:@"hk.xml" sectionForRow:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cc getShopList:cell withXMLFile:@"hk.xml" withIndexPathSection:indexPath.section withIndexPathRow:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {   
    return [cc getShopSectionTitle:section];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to use a property enherit from the [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView)

> contentInset
>   The distance that the content view is inset from the enclosing scroll view.
>   @property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets contentInset
>   Discussion
>   Use this property to add to the scrolling area around the content. The unit of size is points. The default value is UIEdgeInsetsZero.

With that property you can inset the table view by the high of the UITabBar.

OR

You could change the Frame of your UITableView to not go under the UITabBar

OR

Can you tell us how the UITableViewController and the UITabBarController are set?
There can be an issue there.

---

When you say `under` do you mean something like this :

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UITableViewController *tt = [[TableTest alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableTest" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, tt, nil];
```

To place your UIViewControllers in your `UITabBarController` ? Because I tested that code and it's working properly.

because if you really mean under, like your UITableViewController is not in the `self.tabBarController.viewControllers` and is beneath the taBar, you will have to go with one of the option in my original answer.

Comment: @CharlesYeung ok, but that's not what I've asked for, how you populate the `UITableView` have no impact on your problem, but how and when you create it, it's an other story. Are you creating your UITableView in code, is it done in IB, how? What settings? Did you put it into the UITabBar, or other.

Comment: I created the UITableView in Xocde 4 by File > New File > UITableViewController, with XIB for user interface. So the tableview is created in IB. I just use the default setting of the TableView. Also it is put under UITabBar.

Comment: I added view controllers in StoryBoard. After setting ` self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 49, 0);` in `viewDidLoad`, problem was fixed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the height of the UITableView dynamically as discussed in a similar question: [UITableView partially hidden by UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423088/uitableview-partially-hidden-by-uitabbar).

Answer (score 0):

Decrease your TableView's height by 44 points, lets say you have programatically created tableView in loadView then CGRectMake(0,0,320,460) then change 460 height to 416 or in Interface Builder xib file. Reduce it by 44 points. TabBar is overlayed on top of your tableView so last cell seems overlapped by tabbarcontroller.