# MonoTouch: UITabBar overlaps UITableView

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uitabbar, overlapping

If I have UITabBar and UITableView, then UITabBar object will overlap over UITableView.

How can I solve this in MonoTouch?

This is the same problem as in thi article: [Partially hidded by UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423088/uitableview-partially-hidden-by-uitabbar)

Comment: Tried something what is described here [ViewDidAppear](http://aralbalkan.com/2149), but still no luck.

Comment: Show us the code (and where it's called) that you use the create the UI elements. That will give us some hints to help you

Comment: No code necessary. Here is how to provoke it:<br />
- Create Tabbed application in MonoTouch. That will create 2 pages, with UITabBar component on the bottom
- Then drop UITableView control on one of those pages. UITableView control will properly align in IB to the top of the UITabBar (not behind it)
- Then assign more elements to UITableView then it can fit in the view
- When you run the app, and start to scroll down the UITableView, the last element will be hidden behind UITabBar. If you pull up the table, you will see it, but when you release the pull, it will go behind the tab bar again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. By default MonoTouch extends controller from UIViewController. If this is changed to UITableViewController, then overlapping will be solved.

In doing this, make sure you assign Owner's view outlet in IB to the table inside of UITableViewController.